# Simple example of SetExpressCheckout call for creating Multiple Recurring Payment Profile

Tags: php, paypal

I would like to create multiple recurring payment profiles in one step with Express Cehckout, I have been trying to accomplish this for 2 days now, but I stumbling into different problems not explained in the documentation. So what i need is:

- creating multiple recurring payment profiles within one SetExpressCheckout -> DoExpressCheckout -> Create profile
- I might need to do one-time charges as well (so there would be multiple recurring profile creations + instant charges)

Is this possible? If yes HOW? Can anyone point me to a working example on how to accomplish this?

ANY HELP IS MUCH APPRECIATED!

Answer (score 0):

No, this is not possible unfortunately.

What you could do, however, is use Adaptive Preapproved Payments, and set up a single preapproval, with the funds distributed over multiple (parallel or chained) receivers.

This way you could still bill a buyer on a recurring basis (initiated by you), for up to one year, and distribute funds among different receiver(s).

If you decide to go this way, I would suggest reading up on the following documents:

1) Adaptive Payments developers guide: [ https://cms.paypal.com/cms_content/US/en_US/files/developer/PP_AdaptivePayments.pdf ]
2) General Information on apps.: [ https://www.x.com/community/ppx/apps101 ]
3) How to use the PayPal Sandbox testing environment: [ https://cms.paypal.com/cms_content/US/en_US/files/developer/PP_Sandbox_UserGuide.pdf ]

4) Code Samples: [ https://www.x.com/community/ppx/code_samples ]
5) Code generation wizard: [ https://www.paypal-labs.com/integrationwizard/adaptive/ ]

The first link also includes information on how to use the Embedded Payments Interface.